# Update Column in Table from View

Tags: sql, oracle

I am already sitting on this since some time and I don´t get it. Especially since there are examples on SO, which apparently work.

I have one table where I want to update all rows of a single column. The data comes from a View. They are connected with normal values. No Primary/Foreign key Relationship.

I have tried:

```
update table set columnupdate = (SELECT View.data
                              FROM View
                              WHERE table.id= View.id);
```

->"Subquery more than one row."

I guess that I have to "flatten" it somehow, but how?

Or:

```
  update (select a.data as old, p.columnupdate as new
    from table p
    join View a on a.id= p.id) t
set t.new = t.old;
```

-> "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"

So, how do I update data returned by a Join?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "flatten it". You need to tell the database exactly which row you want to take the value from. Or if all the values for that ID are the same, you could use DISTINCT, or take the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery that used in update is returning more than 1 row:

```
 SELECT View.data
 FROM View
 WHERE table.id= View.id
```

And that is the reason you get error `Subquery more than one row.`.
In that case, database found more than 1 row in View, for a row in `table` that you want to update, and bassicly it doesnt know which value it should pick.

Simply change `WHERE` clause to different, or just add rownum to it, to make sure that only one row is returned.
Your update would work, if you would do it this way:

```
UPDATE table SETcolumnupdate = 
( 
 SELECT View.data
 FROM View
 WHERE table.id= View.id
 AND rownum=1
);
```

If you want to update your table for each row in your View, you can do it in PLSQL block by using for loop, for example:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT id, data FROM View)
  LOOP
     UPDATE table SET columnupdate=rec.data where table.id=rec.id;
     --optional commit or rollback here
  END LOOP;
END;
```